# Other elements go down when hidden div is displayed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wrote a `toggler` for 2 `divs` as shown [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9evah2zo/) It works successfully in my website. However other elements below hidden div go down. I don't want that to happen. Here is the screen shot for more clarity:
`before clicking div:`
[image: img]
`after clicking div:`
[image: img1]
You can see that `fill your information here` and `or` div are going down. I don't want that to happen. Those should stay where they are as shown in `before clicking div` screen shot. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you add your code here?

Comment: your  problem is not reflecting in your fiddle , please update it so that it will be easy to solve

Comment: the container thats holding your `Registration | Activation | Reset Password` (lets call it `#container`) should be set with a `position: absolute` and the container where `#container` resides in should be set to `position: relative`

Comment: Apologies, here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9evah2zo/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add the following to your CSS: Here's an update to your [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9evah2zo/7/)

```
#hidden{
   ...
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `position: absolute;` to `#hidden`. Later you can control its position by adding `top` and `left` properties in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [CSS property `z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) on your base page elements and/or the "floating" menu? This allows you to "stack" web page elements so that some elements can "cover" or  float on top of other page elements.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9evah2zo/1/)

for "fill your info..." `div` give `padding-top:(equal to height of the div that you are toggling)`

```
#hidden {
   position:absolute;
   top: (equal to height of your header)
}
```

Comment: I'd not add `top`, it'd mess up my UI, but adding `position:absolute;` fixed it. Thank you